# Compile R packages from source on macOS Big Sur running on ARM silicon

Tags: r, macos, gcc, compiler-errors, apple-m1

When trying to compile R packages from source I ran into one of the following errors:

1. `make: gfortran-11: No such file or directory`
2. `configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`

## My setup

1. Installed [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) which seems to now live under `/opt/homebrew` instead of `/usr/local` (see ["This script installs Homebrew to its preferred prefix (/usr/local for macOS Intel, /opt/homebrew for Apple Silicon [...]"](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation))
2. Installed Xcode and the CLI "the manual way" as described [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-download-and-install-xcode/)
3. Installed `brew install gcc`
4. Created `./R/Makevars` with the following content (which I don't understand and puzzled together from various posts):

   ```
   VER=-11
   CC=gcc$(VER)
   CXX=g++$(VER)
   CXX11=g++$(VER)
   CXX14=g++$(VER)
   CXX17=g++$(VER)
   CFLAGS=-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion
   CXXFLAGS=-mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion
   FLIBS=-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0/lib/gcc/11
   FC=gfortran$(VER)
   CPPFLAGS += -Xclang -fopenmp
   LDFLAGS += -lomp
   ```
5. As suggested in the thread of this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/191), I also created `$R_HOME/etc/Makevars` with the identical content of `./R/Makevars`
6. Then I ran `install.packages("igraph", type = "source") and currently get the following result:

   ```
   > install.packages("igraph", type = "source")
   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/igraph_1.2.6.tar.gz'
   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2715500 bytes (2.6 MB)
   ==================================================
   downloaded 2.6 MB

   * installing *source* package ‘igraph’ ...
   ** package ‘igraph’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
   ** using staged installation
   checking for gcc... gcc-11
   checking whether the C compiler works... no
   configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/ry/bnfxqrqd1bd4mxtvgvnsr9j80000gn/T/Rtmp5mvh5Q/R.INSTALL31ea32410e8e/igraph':
   configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
   See `config.log' for more details
   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘igraph’
   * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/igraph’
   * restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/igraph’
   Warning in install.packages :
     installation of package ‘igraph’ had non-zero exit status
   ```
7. [Here](https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/191#issuecomment-932022413) is a summary of what I *think* I learned/understood so far and what I still need to figure out.

## System info

- Big Sur 11.6
- Homebrew 3.2.14
- Xcode 13
- R 4.0.5

  ```
  sessionInfo()
  R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
  Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
  Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6

  Matrix products: default
  LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

  locale:
  [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

  attached base packages:
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
  [7] base     

  loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
   [1] compiler_4.0.5    htmltools_0.5.1.1 tools_4.0.5      
   [4] yaml_2.2.1        rmarkdown_2.8     knitr_1.33       
   [7] xfun_0.23         digest_0.6.27     rlang_0.4.11     
  [10] evaluate_0.14
  ```

## DISCLAIMER

I'm pretty new to the macOS world in general and pretty much know nothing about compilers, C or Fortran - so please explain things to me like you would to your rubber duck or a 5 year old ;-)

Comment: Have you installed [gfortran](https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases) as the [documentation](https://mac.r-project.org/tools/) advises?

Comment: Personally, I just follow [guides from someone who knows what they are talking about](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/).

Comment: @Roland yes, I did via `brew install gcc`, forgot to mention this. Thanks for the pointer, I'll check it out

Comment: If I remember it correctly you need to install gfortran separately with `brew install gfortran`.

Comment: @Roland Glancing over the [post](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/) you suggested: seems be be from before Big Sur/ARM and AFAIU things have changed compared to x86 architectures. Examples are "[... installs Homebrew to its preferred prefix (/usr/local for macOS Intel, /opt/homebrew for Apple Silicon ...](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation)" and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/jw9guu/why_did_homebrew_move_from_usrlocalto_opthomebrew/). Not sure if it's only related to Homebrew's gcc or a general change for compiler aspects

Comment: @nameiki I think `gfortran` ships with `gcc` when installed via `brew install gcc` and I can access it from the terminal (checked via `which gfortran` and `gfortran -v`). See https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gcc